# How to get a smooth transition between two objects. Two perpendicular cylinders

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to create a smooth transition between 2 objects.
I thought I would start simple with 2 cylinders.

In the image below, I have created two cylinders, one slightly smalller than the other. I have simply used a boolean union, which I have applied. After this I have used a subdivision surface, to give it a smooth transition between the two. The issue as you can see is that it creates an undesired optical effect.

I've tried using a bevel, which just messes up. I've tried using a bevel modifier, which works at a very small scale. I'm looking for something like the hairdryer image attached - a smooth transition.

Am I modelling this the wrong way? If so, what would be better?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

1. create a lip to the connecting piece
2. assign a vertex group to the lip vertices
3. add the `Shrinkwrap Modifier` to the handle, selecting the other cynlinder as target and using the created vertex group play around with the `Mode` to suit your needs).

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is great, it seems to have gotten me 95% of the way there. I still can still see a clear join between the two pieces, unlike your model. How can I make it super smooth?

Answer (score 0):

You could try sculpting the shape. I would either create a circle to use as a guide or if you are familiar with python, write a python script to sculpt it for you.

Comment: I'd prefer to use block modelling here if possible. I'm looking to create product visuals, so keeping true to angles and dimensions is helpful.